# How to retrieve information from table in one statement when the result has different numbers of rows?

Tags: sql

I want to retrieve different information in one statement from the same table and they have different number of rows.

The first select has five rows in the result and the second select has three rows because some prices have null value. I thought maybe if I can put zero instead of null so they will match the same number of rows but I don't know how to do that, or is there another solution?

```
select count(ID), Land 
from Film_ha2911 
group by Land 

union 

select count(ID) 
from Film_ha2911 
where Price is not null 
group by Land;
```

Comment: Tags been adjusted. Is the database engine - SQL Server or MySQL ?

Comment: I need it only sql, what i had to add beside it ?

Comment: Various database engines have differences in SQL syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of UNION implies  that the number and type of columns in select must corresponding
so in your case  you should use  null for not select columns

```
select count(ID), Land 
from Film_ha2911 
group by Land 
union 
select count(ID), null  
from Film_ha2911 
where Price is not null 
group by Land;
```

But in this case seems you need  a left join on the  subquery for land

```
select  t1.count1, t1.land , t2.count2
from (
  select count(ID) count1, Land 
  from Film_ha2911 
  group by Land 
) t1 
left join  (
  select count(ID) count2, land  
  from Film_ha2911 
  where Price is not null 
  group by Land;
) t2 on t1.land = t2.land
```

Comment: what you call this you did in the first line (t1.count1, t1.land , t2.count2) it looks to me like you created variables and used them. what this process called. can you explain it more or give me something i can search more about it?

Comment: @Birouti   .. these as not variable  .. these are column name  (table_name.column_name) these columns a select from the subquery .. from( select ...)   the use of t1 for a  table name or count1 for a column name is named  alias  .. table alias or column alias .. and is often use in sql for a better readibility e for an easy column  reference management ..

Answer (score 0):

The desired result can be achieved by single SELECT without UNION.
Extra column: PriceNotNull to differentiate is Price value filled or not:

```
SELECT 
    Land,
    CASE  WHEN Price IS NOT NULL THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END  PriceNotNull,
    COUNT(ID)  AS Count_ID
FROM Film_ha2911
GROUP BY Land, CASE  WHEN Price IS NOT NULL THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `count()`:

```
select Land, count(*) as total_rows,
       count(price) as total_with_price
from Film_ha2911 
group by Land;
```

`count()` counts the number of non-`NULL` values, so no special logic is needed to count non-`NULL` values.  By `count(id)` I assume you want to count all the rows.  `count(*)` is more explicit -- as would `count(1)` which some people prefer.

If you actually want this on separate rows, I would add an indicator for what the count means:

```
select Land, 'total rows' as which, count(*) as total_rows
from Film_ha2911 
group by Land
union all
select Land, 'with price', count(price)
from Film_ha2911 
group by Land;
```

However, I think the first version with two separate columns is more useful.